# Keycloack Wiremock testing a custom extension

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-oidc

I am building an extension to support my company's internal and external SSO options. All other things being equal... given this sample block of code...

```
@QuarkusTestResource(OidcWiremockTestResource.class)
class SsoAutowiredTest {

  @RegisterExtension
  static final QuarkusUnitTest UNIT_TEST = QuarkusUnitTest.withSecuredConnection()
        // config option 1
        .overrideConfigKey("quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url", "${keycloak.url}/realms/quarkus/")
        // config option 2
        //.overrideConfigKey("security.oidc.sso.internal.auth-server-url", "${keycloak.url}/realms/quarkus/")
        .setArchiveProducer(() -> ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addClass(SecureResource.class));

  @Test
  void test() {
  }

}
```

The code as is, with "option 1" uncommented works.
However, if I comment out "option 1", and uncomment "option 2", I get the following exception:

Caused by: io.smallrye.config.ConfigValidationException: Configuration validation failed:
java.util.NoSuchElementException: SRCFG00011: Could not expand value keycloak.url in property security.oidc.sso.internal.auth-server-url

Why is that? There is otherwise no difference. I am not sure why the substituted ${keycloak.url} should care how it is used.

Thank you in advance,
Dennis